# PSTricks code exported from Geogebra generate errors

Tags: pstricks, geogebra

I try to compile PSTricks pictures with the PSTricks code generated by Geogebra, but this generates errors. For example the following code doesn't compile.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=0.7cm,yunit=0.7cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-0.5,-0.5)(9.5,5.5)
    \psline[linewidth=2pt](0,5)(9,5)
    \psline[linewidth=2pt](9,5)(9,0)
    \psline[linewidth=2pt](9,0)(0,0)
    \psline[linewidth=2pt](0,0)(0,5)
    \psline[linewidth=2pt](3,5)(3,0)
    \psline[linewidth=2pt](6,5)(6,0)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Even a single point generates errors:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newrgbcolor{ududff}{0.30196078431372547 0.30196078431372547 1.}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=2.pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-4.3,-2.56)(7.06,6.3)
\begin{scriptsize}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=ududff](-2.18,3.44)
\rput[bl](-2.1,3.64){\ududff{$A$}}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Does someone have a solution?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you compile? Which errors did you have?

Comment: Compile with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I compiled with LaTeX, and here are the errors:

Undefined control sequence. \psline[linewidth=2pt](

Undefined control sequence. \psline[linewidth=2pt](

Undefined control sequence. \psline

Undefined control sequence. \psline

Undefined control sequence. \psline[linewidth=2pt](

Undefined control sequence. \psline[linewidth=2pt](

Undefined control sequence. \psline

Undefined control sequence. \psline

Undefined control sequence. \psline[linewidth=2pt](

Undefined control sequence. \psline[linewidth=2pt](

... and so on. With Lualatex it does the same.

Comment: I have no problem  compiling with `xelatex --shell-escape`.

Comment: No problem compiling with  `latex <filename>`. If you are an `AUCTeX` user, you have to add `\usepackage{pstricks}` in the preamble to configure the compilation automatically.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It appears that it was about configuring the right settings for compilation and for vizualisation (I use TeXstudio).

Comment: works fine with lualatex for me, but it requires a quite current texsystem.